# FacebookConnectPlugin does not callback after login in Cordova application

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I'm using Cordova 3.5 and using [facebook connect plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin). AI built my application successfuly and deployed to my device. When I try to login facebook, Facebook prompts me about the login request and permissions. After accepting or rejecting this, no callback function is triggered. I tried lots of different ways but no chance. I built my app for android.

Here is the code I'm calling facebook login.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["basic_info"], function (data) { alert("Success"); }, function (error) { alert("Failed"); });
```

It does not alert neither"Success" nor "Failed".

Does anybody have an idea? I searched a lot but could not find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figured that out? I faced this problem too, but my app for iOS. btw, read this thread. Seems that it's cordova issue, because after trying to login FB method behaves like user clicked "Cancel login" https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/pull/561

Comment: I found it, i wrote it down as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out;

If the facebook plugin throws an exception, it does not fire your fail callback. I debugged the facebook pluggin source code in Eclipse. In my case the problem was the application hashkey. Just because key is wrong, it throws an exception in deep and does not show that to you.

If you are facing this, try to find if there is an inner exception.